PHP echo out an href that contains javascript and php variables
Consider the following href:
<a href="javascript:loadRightMain('director_u.mv?func=1215&sub1=0&SRVID=<?php echo $srvs['id']; ?>&CLIENTID=<?php echo $CLIENTID; ?>');">$</a>

I would like to echo the entire href inside php tags more like:
<?php

echo "<a href="javascript:loadRightMain('director_u.mv?func=1215&sub1=0&SRVID=".$srvs['id']."&CLIENTID=".$CLIENTID."');">$</a>";

?>

Of course the issue is with all the conflicting single and/or double quotes.
Is there a way to do this? Or am I approaching the whole idea wrong?

Why do you need/want to do this? What's wrong with the code you have now? IMHO it's more natural, and of course you have no additional headache of the escaping of quote marks

Well, because this href will be repeated in iteration within a foreach loop, and if I exit the php container, I will loose the loop structure.

Actually... Maybe I am wrong about loosing the loop. As it this (to my suprise) works :

<a href="javascript:loadLeftBtm('director.php?func=1012&REFID=<?php echo $clients['id']; ?>'); resize_leftform_sm();" > <?php echo $clients['name']; ?> </a> 



<?php } ?>


Please use http_build_query() to build your querystring in a valid, stable, and maintainable way. https://3v4l.org/lVng3

@mickmackusa I was unaware of http_build_query. Thank you!
